# Accessing MySQL from Powershell on Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, mysql, powershell

I'm trying to access MySQL via PowerShell running on Ubuntu 18 and having some trouble loading the Assembly.  Below is the code as it runs on Windows.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")
$Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()
$Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($query, $Connection)
$DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
$returnVariable = $DataSet.Tables[0]
```

The line PS on Ubuntu throws an error is line 1
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")

I've tried copying some dlls from the local windows PC to the same folder to see if that makes a difference.

MySQL server IS running on the ubuntu machine I am running the script on.

Is this possible or is my syntax wrong for PS on Ubuntu or do I need to load something else on the server?

I will continue with my searches, but not coming up with much at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This was a syntax issue:

`[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")`

Changed to:

`add-type -path "/home/ubuntu/MySql.Data.dll"`

and it runs successfully now.